# Confused by a python -c printing command "\xef\xbe\xad\xde" what does it mean?

Tags: python, c, printing, stack, exploit

I am reading the "Hacker's Playbook 2" and was reading a bit about binary exploitation, and trying out an ssh game with some C code, and if you exploit these you get the password to the next level. However I was very confused by a python printing command used by the owner of the book hoping you guys would explain. Check it out:

[the C code and requirements of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avc60.png)

[the confusing python printing statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VmfW.png)

I tried to explain it the best I could by adding the two pictures, and as you can se the part which confuses me is: **"\xef\xbe\xad\xde"**

I hope I was clear, and thanks in return :)

Comment: `\xef` is the hexadecimal value `ef` which in decimal is `239.

Comment: Those are hex char codes. Similar to `chr(0xef) + chr(0xbe) + chr(0xad) + chr(0xde)`

Comment: Could you accept my answer, please, if it is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python strings, you can specify characters by giving their ASCII, ISO Latin-1 or Unicode ordinal values in hexadecimal (base-16) notation. To do this, you include substrings of the form `"\xHH"` in your string, where `HH` is a number in hexadecimal. For instance, to include the carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) characters in a string, you would write `"My string\x0D\x0A"`. 0D in hexadecimal corresponds to 13 decimal, which is the ASCII code for a carriage return, and 0A corresponds to 10, which is a line feed.

In this case, the book author is specifying the Latin-1 code points `"\xEF"` (hex EF = decimal 239), `"\xBE"` (190), `"\xAD"` (173) and `"\xDE"` (222). They are apparently chosen for comic value so that the result of his shenanigans can be shown as `"DEADBEEF"`.